# Argument abbreviations with non-consecutive lettering (partial matching++)?

Tags: r

This is a long shot, but is there a way to specify abbreviations for argument names that aren't consecutive in letter order?  Partial matching doesn't work well for some very long descriptive names.

Examples: (format is "`long name` - `typical partial match` - `what I'd like`")

- `,stringsAsFactors` - `,strings` - `,saf` or `,asfact`
- `,market_initial` - `,mark` - `,mkt`
- `,rebalanceFunction` - `,rebalance` - `,rebfn`

This is not a huge deal, and I can see how it would cause more problems than it's worth, but there are some cases where I have a convention for abbreviations across a package and it's weird to break them just because a particular argument is more descriptive (because it's using it in a particular way).  So the long form could tell the user exactly how it's being used in this particular function, but in the short form people would understand what its use is and I could keep the convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just add the answer I've given to you in the chat. If you look at how the R core developers do that for different arguments, you just use the function declaration for that. From read.table , which contains an argument `as.is` and an argument `stringsAsFactors` that do exactly the same (or actually the opposite) :

```
function (file, -some pars-, as.is = !stringsAsFactors, -some more pars -
    stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(), -more pars - ) 
{
    #function code using as.is 
}
```

Thing is, this only works if you specify a default value for either of them. Pretty often, NULL is a good candidate :

```
myfunc <- function(x, market_initial=NULL, mkt = market_initial, ...){

    if(is.null(mkt)) { 
        print("give me market_initial!") # instead of missing(mkt)
    } else {
        print(mkt)
    }

}
```